# Can't seem to have it print out "round 1. rounds 2, ext"

Tags: python, linux

```
guess = input("H or T?")

def game():
    num_rounds()
    for p1 in range(0, 2):
        p1 = ("H", "T")
        p2 = random.choice(p1)
        guess1 = input("What was your pick?")

    for p1 in p2:
         if p1 == guess1:
            print("I win this round!")
         if p1 != guess1:
            print('You win this round!')
    for p1 in range(0, 8):
        p1 = ("H", "T")
        p2 = random.choice(p1)
        guess1 = input("What was your pick?")
    for p1 in p2:
        if p1 == guess1:
            print("I win this round!")
        elif p1 != guess1:
            print('You win this round!')

    print("Thanks for playing!")
    quit()
```

rounds = 10
   for round in range(rounds):
      print("Round", round)
      game()

I want it to print out:

```
Round 1: Choose H or T.
```

before it starts the game play

Comment: Have your tried using a `for` or `while ` loop? [Python looping structures](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm)

Comment: What have you tried? What's the actual issue you're having? Show some effort.

Comment: @JanHančič I've tried this: import random  rounds=10 for round in range(rounds):

Comment: I've tried the for loop and it only printed out                                               Round 0
What was your pick?>? H

Answer (score -2):

define the rounds and then use the range() for the amount of time and use the for loop to have this repeating of the rounds you want. Actually try next time....